# Kotlin Activity changes writing order from left to right to right to left (Phone w/ different language)

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, kotlin-extension, left-to-right

I have a Kotlin project in Android Studio and I developed a simple app...

My real device is in a different language so when I run the app on my device all the activity is stuck to the right (like you write in Hebrew...)
I want to keep the order left to right (like in English and won't change based on the phone's language)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the android Manifest file make sure to Disable RTL:

```
<application
    android:supportsRtl="false"
```

This disables the Right to Left feature for your app, so if the setting is on in your device settings the app will not change.